# View current media storage used?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way to view the current total media storage GB used? I know the Spark plan has 5GB of media hosting, but I cannot find a way to view storage remaining.

I have a folder that has a bunch of pictures, but the `Size` just shows `-`.

[image]

The console does not have a way to view it like the database console does.

**Media Console**

[image]

**Database Console**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to navigate to your project in the [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com). Then in the upper right select `Activate Google Shell Cloud`, and then `START CLOUD SHELL`.

Once the shell window is open simply type `gsutil du -s gs://your bucket link/`, then hit enter.

For example, in my original post I want to find the total size of the "images" storage bucket. I would type `gsutil du -s gs://myproject.appspot.com/images/`. This will return the total size of the `image` bucket in `Bytes`. Then, if you need to, you can [convert Bytes to GBs](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bytes+to+gb&*).

This will show you the total size of your bucket.